# Is there a limit of sqoop.export.records.per.statement for Sqoop Export job?

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, sqoop, vertica

Does anyone know if there is a limit for the value of sqoop.export.records.per.statement for Sqoop batch export job?

I have very large size of data, like 200,000,000 rows of data to export, from Impala to Vertica. I will get `[Vertica][VJDBC](5065) ERROR: Too many ROS containers exist for the following projections` if records per statement is set too low, or `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` if records per statement is set too high.

Anyone know how to fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the limit is that of memory.  If you increase the heap it'll let you set the number higher.  Try adding `-D mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx1024M` or some larger number than your current settings?

You could try to increase `export.statements.per.transaction` and reduce your records per statement. I'm thinking this won't help on the ROS container side because I am thinking each batch of SQL = 1 COPY statement = 1 ROS container.  I don't think it'll convert multiple batches of INSERTs into a single COPY, but I don't have a way to test it right now.

You could bypass sqoop and stream the data (You may need to construct the COPY), something like:

```
impala-shell -k -i server:port -B -q 'select * from mytable' --output_delimiter="|" | vsql -h database_host -U user -w password -c 'copy mytable from stdin direct'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm trying the per.transaction option now, let's see how it works. And by the way, our current solution is vsql direct copy, but export to local file first and then vsql copy from local file. From your script, does this mean that it's not needed to export to file first, am I right? Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `mkfifo` and write to it in one process and load from it in another.  The example I gave above streams the data.  It might not be 100%, but if you run the first command, you should see the exact data to be loaded with no headers or footer. If so, that can be piped right into the second command as I showed above.   You might have to adjust based on delimiters, etc.

Comment: As you said, per.transaction didn't work well for "too many ros files" error. I will try the COPY solution then. Since it doesn't need to export to file, it might have improvement in processing time. Thank you very much!

Comment: Get it working in two parts first (export the data to a file using `> output.txt` and then import it using `cat output.txt | vsql...`.  Doing it in parts will make the development easier.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I've tested them separately and both works fine. Successfully export to target directory and import part also works well. But not together. One reason is that "-o --output_delimiter="|"" will make a file called --output_delimiter="|" to current directory. Do you know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: oops. Sorry I don't have it a command I can test with but try: `-o -` or removing it entirely.  Sorry about that.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer!

Comment: @yuan0122 Could you edit the answer with regards to the `-o`?  I'm not sure if removing it or using `-o -` was the right method and have no way to test it.